# PHP Using a foreach loop in $_POST

Tags: php, mysql, post, foreach

I have a table I am submitting to a db. Each row in my table has:
1. row_id
2. first_name
3. last_name

```
          <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Row ID</th>
                <th>first name</th>
                <th>last name</th>
                <th>email</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
```

***********  Query from DB       **************

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM basic ";
$select_all_query = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_all_query)){
    $first_name = $row['first_name'];
    $last_name = $row['last_name'];
    $email = $row['email'];


echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='row_id[]' value='$i'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='first_name[]' value='$first_name'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='last_name[]' value='$last_name'></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='emai[]' value='$email'></td>";
echo "</tr>";
$i++;
}
```

When I click submit I run my if isset function, the foreach loop is going through the table the correct amount of times (I look in the db and see the same amount of rows as on my table) however it is only capturing 1 row of values and duplicating them on on the rows in the db.

Here is my submit code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    foreach($_POST['row_id'] as $id){
       $row_id = $_POST['row_id'];
       $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
       $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];

$query = "INSERT INTO test_db(first_name, last_name) VALUES('{$first_name}', '{$last_name}')";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if(!$result){die("QUERY FAILED " . mysqli_error($connection));}
    if(!$connection){echo "NOT connected";}
   }
print_r($_POST);
}
```

print_r displays

```
Array ( [submit] => Submit [row_id] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 ) [first_name] => Array ( [0] => David [1] => Jane [2] => Jack [3] => Sam ) [last_name] => Array ( [0] => Smith [1] => Doe [2] => Pipper [3] => Gibbens ) [email] => Array ( [0] => ds@email.com [1] => jd@email.com [2] => jp@email.com [3] => sg@email.com ) )
```

The data is coming into the table from a different SQL database table, so when it runs through its while loop I get the data and move it around into the format needed.

Is there a way to have the submit capture the values for each row and have the foreach run through those rows submitting the values?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query.

Comment: Please edit above to post the output from `print_r($_POST)`. It isn't obvious what your post actually contains, whether multi-value keys or single.

Comment: Not `$_POST['row_id']`, here `$row_id = $_POST['row_id'];`, that is an array (?), use `$id`. You need to pull the key as well and then get the corresponding names. Also as noted use parameterized query as well.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski nice!! This question is very poor!

Comment: I added the print_r @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: I only have 4 rows right now, but as you can see from the print_r it is only getting 1 of them

Comment: Looking at the form code, you will need `[]` on the other form inputs like you have on `row_id`. Once you've added that, then update the output from `print_r()`.

Comment: I added the [] to each inputs and that gives me the array I need, but I now also get Notice: Array to string conversion on my INSERT query

Comment: `$_POST['first_name']` and the last are arrays now. You need to pull the `key` that the `id` record matches them with.

Comment: Because the 3 below are arrays not values. Check something like that: Your  `$row_id = $id;`
      `$first_name = $_POST['first_name'][$id];`
       `$last_name = $_POST['last_name'][$id];`

Comment: AWESOME!! Thank you thats it. I have been working on this for a little over a week. I am new to php as you could probably tell. thank you all for your help.